# IONIC start error

Tags: ionic-framework

Im trying to fix this issue from 5 hours now and i still can't fix it i'm to start ionic and serve it but i get this error all the time i did everything on the internet to fix but still nothing

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications.`npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)
```

i tried all these commands :

```
sudo npm install ios-sim -g
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true

npm install -g ios-deploy --allow-root
```

my ERROR

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-sim"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /Users/heshamelmasry/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ios-sim
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/heshamelmasry/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ios-sim'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/heshamelmasry/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ios-sim'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/heshamelmasry/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ios-sim' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/heshamelmasry/Desktop/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: did you try to create a blank app?

Comment: try to clen npm cache, remove npm package and install it again with sudo

Comment: It's saying "EACESS" so its a permission error, have you tried running this command from a terminal with admin privileges